# How to load jsp page some data content dynamically without using javascript or ajax? Because my IE8 browser doesn't support most javascript tags?

Tags: jsp, servlets, iframe, ejb-3.0, dynamic-data

I want to add dynamic data content from my database through ejb and servlet into my B div place without changing A background data css or other designs. How I do this? Is I can any help from IFRAME? How can I do this?
Here B is middle space and A is outer layout.

Comment: Firstly, iframe is a good alternative. Also, why do you think most javascript tags are not supported in IE8, my sites' ajax just work perfect on IE8 too. Try using jquery or something alike for ajax.

Comment: Because my i coded advanced search in my jsp page. I pass data into my javascript function and got getelementby Id and using ajax i send request and load page with searched data and worked fine in chrome,firefox..but not in IE8. I got advised some other, the reason ie 8 doesn't support. I thought that most javascript doesn't support. Am I wrong? I'm new to coding.If can explain me.

Comment: Try using jquery... it shall work fine. There's nothing as such that JS don't work on IE8.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery 1.9 (early 2013): We’ll remove many of the interfaces already deprecated 
in version 1.8; some of them will be available as plugins or alternative APIs 
supported by the jQuery project. IE 6/7/8 will be supported as today.
```

says http://blog.jquery.com/2012/06/28/jquery-core-version-1-9-and-beyond/

So just try using jquery to send the ajax-request.

Below is a small snippet I used from one of my projects.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "tradecopy.action",
            data: $("#tradecopyform").serialize(),
            complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
                $("#innerModalPopupDiv").html(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I'm new to ajax.Please if you can send me a code how to send a html hidden field id into ajax request. Beacuse my main purpose is to send an hidden field id into ajax request and send into my servlet.

Comment: `data: "hiddenfield="+$("#hiddenfield").val(),`

Comment: Than you so much your reply.I will try.One thing to I have to ask.In here response comes to "complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
                $("#innerModalPopupDiv").html(xhr.responseText);
            }" tag I think.Does response should html  or our response data auto generate to html page?

Comment: If you have please send me a code of send ajax request and load servlet related data into that ajax used page. I'm new to ajax.That's why I'm that much of bothering.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
http://www.bennadel.com/resources/presentations/jquery/demo21/
http://www.jquerysample.com/

Comment: Thank you for your helping hand.I think those links very helpful for me.